# Filter link array by Jquery attr.()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple link elements in my DOM and want to search for a specific one by its `href` attribute.

**The code that works:**
(removes the second link after filtering for the matching href)

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

  const ele = getLinkElementByUrl("/link2");

  $(ele).remove();

});

const getLinkElementByUrl = (url) => {

  const links = $(".l"); // find all links
  var element = null;

  for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    let ele = links[i];
    let href = $(ele).attr('href');

    if (href == url) { // matching href?
      element = ele;
      break;
    }

  }

  return element;
}
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="l" href="/link1">Link 1</a>
<br>
<a class="l" href="/link2">Link 2</a>
<br>
<a class="l" href="/link3">Link 3</a>
```

I want the code getting shorten. I tried out this code

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

  const ele = getLinkElementByUrl("/link2");

  $(ele).remove();

});

const getLinkElementByUrl = (url) => {
  return $(".l").find(current => $(current.attr('href')) == url);
}
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="l" href="/link1">Link 1</a>
<br>
<a class="l" href="/link2">Link 2</a>
<br>
<a class="l" href="/link3">Link 3</a>
```

The search function returns me an empty array instead of the matching link element.

Is my syntax wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of finding element using **jQuery [attribute$=value] Selector**

```
const getLinkElementByUrl = (url) => {
  return $("a[href$='/link2']")
}
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/LdrjVJ

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

  const ele = getLinkElementByUrl("/link2");
  //console.log("ele",ele);

  $(ele).remove();

});

const getLinkElementByUrl = (url) => {
  return $("a[href$='/link2']")
}
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="l" href="/link1">Link 1</a>
<br>
<a class="l" href="/link2">Link 2</a>
<br>
<a class="l" href="/link3">Link 3</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

  const ele = getLinkElementByUrl("/link2");

  $(ele).remove();

});

const getLinkElementByUrl = (url) => {
  return $(".l[href='"+ url + "']:eq(0)");
}
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="l" href="/link1">Link 1</a>
<br>
<a class="l" href="/link2">Link 2</a>
<br>
<a class="l" href="/link3">Link 3</a>
```